# Rust panic::catch_unwind no use in WebAssembly

Tags: rust, webassembly

I try to use `panic::catch_unwind` to catch some errors, but it seems no use, and there is an example:

rust:

```
use std::{sync::Mutex};
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use std::sync::PoisonError;
use std::panic;

pub struct CurrentStatus {
  pub index: i32,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
extern {
  pub fn alert(s: &str);
}


impl CurrentStatus {
  fn new() -> Self {
    CurrentStatus {
      index: 1,
    }
  }
  fn get_index(&mut self) -> i32 {
    self.index += 1;
    self.index.clone()
  }

  fn add_index(&mut self) {
    self.index += 2;
  }
}

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref FOO: Mutex<CurrentStatus> = Mutex::new(CurrentStatus::new());
}

unsafe impl Send for CurrentStatus {}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn add_index() {
  FOO.lock().unwrap_or_else(PoisonError::into_inner).add_index();
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn get_index() -> i32 {
  let mut foo = FOO.lock().unwrap_or_else(PoisonError::into_inner);
  let result = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
    panic!("error happen!"); // original panic! code
  });
  if result.is_err() {
    alert("panic!!!!!panic");
  }
  return foo.get_index();
}
```

js:

```
const js = import("../pkg/hello_wasm.js");
js.then(js => {
  window.js = js;
  console.log(js.get_index());
  js.add_index();
});
```

I think it should catch the panic and I can call `add_index` then.

But In fact I can call neither after the panic.

I wish I can catch the panic from one function so when the users call other functions just all right..

Thanks very much

Comment: Just encountered the same issue, did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

By default wasm builds are set to `panic=abort`, ie exit the program even if there is a `catch_unwind`.

It is possible to set `panic=unwind` as of [this pr](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/111322), but only for `[no_std]` crates.

If you *really* need to there are ways to hack around it, for instance [wasm-bindgen's own test crate](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/blob/ac480862a3c624c9d71d27c06ed65418bb2ef503/crates/test/src/rt/mod.rs#L228) catches panics with the use of `scoped-tls`, it looks something like this:

```rs
scoped_tls::scoped_thread_local!(static CURRENT_OUTPUT: RefCell<Output>);

static SET_HOOK: Once = Once::new();
SET_HOOK.call_once(|| {
    std::panic::set_hook(Box::new(|panic_info| {
        let should_panic = CURRENT_OUTPUT.with(|output| {
            let mut output = output.borrow_mut();
            output.panic.push_str(&panic_info.to_string());
            output.should_panic
        });

        if !should_panic {
           console_error_panic_hook::hook(panic_info);
        }
    }));
});

let result = CURRENT_OUTPUT.set(&output, || {
    let mut test = Some(test);
    __wbg_test_invoke(&mut || {
        let test = test.take().unwrap_throw();
        future_output = Some(test.poll(cx))
    })
});
```